# Select 10 Before and 10 After from Identifiers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Do you think the SQL Statement **BELOW** can be executed in a better way than presented.

Here are the requirements:

1. The query requires TextIdentifier and a User Name
2. Identify 10 MP3 files that were created before, and 10 MP3 files that were created after.
3. If less than 10 MP3 files exist before or after, then pick all available.
4. The auto-number ID in the table cannot be used, since the DateCreated does not correlate

> The code is below the images

**Here are some potential scenarios:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**QUERY:**

```
 DECLARE @UserName NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @TextIdentifier NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @ProximityDate AS DATETIME
    SET @UserName = 'Pete'
    SET @TextIdentifier = '456'

    SELECT  @ProximityDate = [DateCreated]
    FROM    dbo.ProximitySelectTable
    WHERE   UserName = @UserName
            AND TextIdentifier = @TextIdentifier


    SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT TOP 10 *
    FROM    dbo.ProximitySelectTable
    WHERE   UserName = @UserName
            AND [DateCreated] < @ProximityDate
    UNION
    SELECT  *
    FROM    dbo.ProximitySelectTable
    WHERE   UserName = @UserName
            AND TextIdentifier = @TextIdentifier                      
    UNION
    SELECT TOP 10 *
    FROM    dbo.ProximitySelectTable
    WHERE   UserName = @UserName
            AND [DateCreated] > @ProximityDate        
    ) x
    ORDER BY x.DateCreated
```

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TextIdentifier] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FileName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Test DATA**

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable]    Script Date: 06/15/2016 15:15:09 ******/
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ON
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (1, N'2has721', N'Pete', N'c:\123456.mp3', CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (2, N'123', N'Pete', N'c:\223456.mp3', CAST(0x0000A58000000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (3, N'456', N'Pete', N'c:\323456.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5DB00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (4, N'789', N'Pete', N'c:\423456.mp3', CAST(0x0000A58000000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (5, N'1011', N'Pete', N'c:\523456.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5F900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (6, N'1112', N'Jack', N'c:\623456.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5BC00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (7, N'1312', N'Jack', N'c:\723456.mp3', CAST(0x0000A56C00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (8, N'1412', N'Jack', N'c:\823456.mp3', CAST(0x0000A54300000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (9, N'1516', N'Jack', N'c:\923456.mp3', CAST(0x0000A58000000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (10, N'1817', N'Jack', N'c:\133456.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5F900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (11, N'1819', N'Sherry', N'c:\143456.mp3', CAST(0x0000A52400000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (12, N'2021', N'Sherry', N'c:\153456.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5BC00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (13, N'2122', N'Sherry', N'c:\163456.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5DB00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (14, N'2123', N'Pete', N'c:\173456.mp3', CAST(0x0000A52400000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (15, N'2124', N'Pete', N'c:\183456.mp3', CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (16, N'2125', N'Sherry', N'c:\193456.mp3', CAST(0x0000A50600000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (17, N'2126', N'Jack', N'c:\124456.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5BC00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (18, N'2127', N'Pete', N'c:\125456.mp3', CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (19, N'2128', N'Sherry', N'c:\aaaa1.mp3', CAST(0x0000A4E700000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (20, N'2129', N'Jack', N'c:\aaaa2.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5F900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (21, N'3121', N'Jack', N'c:\aaaa3.mp3', CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (22, N'3122', N'Sherry', N'c:\aaaa4.mp3', CAST(0x0000A54300000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (23, N'3123', N'Jack', N'c:\aaaa5.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5BC00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (24, N'3124', N'Jack', N'c:\aaaa6.mp3', CAST(0x0000A13900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (25, N'3125', N'Sherry', N'c:\aaaa7.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5DB00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (26, N'3126', N'Jack', N'c:\aaaa8.mp3', CAST(0x0000A56C00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (27, N'3127', N'Pete', N'c:\aaaa9.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5F900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (28, N'3128', N'Pete', N'c:\bbbbb1.mp3', CAST(0x0000A54300000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (29, N'3129', N'Sherry', N'c:\bbbbb2.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5BC00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (30, N'4121', N'Jack', N'c:\bbbbb3.mp3', CAST(0x0000A52400000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (31, N'4122', N'Pete', N'c:\bbbbb4.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5F900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (32, N'4123', N'Jack', N'c:\bbbbb5.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5DB00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (33, N'4124', N'Jack', N'c:\bbbbb6.mp3', CAST(0x0000A50600000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (34, N'4125', N'Sherry', N'c:\bbbbb7.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5BC00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (35, N'4126', N'Jack', N'c:\bbbbb8.mp3', CAST(0x0000A56C00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (36, N'4127', N'Jack', N'c:\bbbbb9.mp3', CAST(0x0000A4E700000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (37, N'4128', N'Jack', N'c:\cccccc1.mp3', CAST(0x0000A54300000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (38, N'4129', N'Pete', N'c:\cccccc2.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5DB00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (39, N'5121', N'Sherry', N'c:\cccccc3.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5BC00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (40, N'5122', N'Jack', N'c:\cccccc4.mp3', CAST(0x0000A56C00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (41, N'5123', N'Jack', N'c:\cccccc5.mp3', CAST(0x0000A54300000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (42, N'5124', N'Sherry', N'c:\cccccc6.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5DB00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (43, N'5125', N'Pete', N'c:\cccccc7.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5BC00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (44, N'5126', N'Jack', N'c:\cccccc8.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5DB00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (45, N'5127', N'Pete', N'c:\cccccc9.mp3', CAST(0x0000A4E700000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (46, N'5128', N'Pete', N'c:\ddddd1.mp3', CAST(0x0000A54300000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (47, N'5129', N'Pete', N'c:\ddddd2.mp3', CAST(0x0000A4E700000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (48, N'6121', N'Pete', N'c:\ddddd3.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5F900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (49, N'6122', N'Pete', N'c:\ddddd4.mp3', CAST(0x0000A50600000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (50, N'6123', N'Pete', N'c:\ddddd5.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5BC00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (51, N'6124', N'Pete', N'c:\ddddd6.mp3', CAST(0x0000A52400000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (52, N'6125', N'Pete', N'c:\ddddd7.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5F900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (53, N'6126', N'Pete', N'c:\ddddd8.mp3', CAST(0x0000A50600000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (54, N'6127', N'Pete', N'c:\ddddd9.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5DB00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] ([ID], [TextIdentifier], [UserName], [FileName], [DateCreated]) VALUES (55, N'6128', N'Jack', N'c:\ddddd0.mp3', CAST(0x0000A5F900000000 AS DateTime))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ProximitySelectTable] OFF
```

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table?

Comment: I would look into a solution that uses ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: Table is brand new, no indexes yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current query is not correct (missing `ORDER BY` and unneeded `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL`) but a fixed version of it could be the most efficient with the right indexes.

My `row_number` answer first is

```
WITH CTE1
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateCreated) AS RN
         FROM   [ProximitySelectTable]
         WHERE  UserName = @UserName),
     CTE2
     AS (SELECT *,
                MAX(CASE
                      WHEN @TextIdentifier = TextIdentifier
                        THEN RN
                    END) OVER () AS FocusRN
         FROM   CTE1)
SELECT ID,
       TextIdentifier,
       UserName,
       FileName,
       DateCreated
FROM   CTE2
WHERE  RN BETWEEN FocusRN - 10 AND FocusRN + 10
ORDER  BY DateCreated
```

And a fixed version of your current query

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM    dbo.ProximitySelectTable
WHERE   UserName = @UserName
        AND [DateCreated] < @ProximityDate
ORDER BY [DateCreated] DESC 
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.ProximitySelectTable
WHERE   UserName = @UserName
        AND TextIdentifier = @TextIdentifier                      
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM    dbo.ProximitySelectTable
WHERE   UserName = @UserName
        AND [DateCreated] > @ProximityDate  
ORDER BY [DateCreated] ASC            
) x
ORDER BY x.DateCreated
```

This would need an index on `UserName, TextIdentifier` for the initial seek and on `UserName, DateCreated` to get the `TOP 10`s with a seek and no sort.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have a box running SQL Server 2008 handy but I checked that all functions below are available in 2008:

```
DECLARE @UserName       NVARCHAR(255) = 'Pete'
DECLARE @TextIdentifier NVARCHAR(255) = '456'

;WITH
    cte1 AS
    (
        SELECT      *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateCreated) AS RowNumber
        FROM        ProximitySelectTable
    ),
    cte2 AS
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
                    RowNumber
        FROM        cte1
        WHERE       UserName = @UserName AND TextIdentifier = @TextIdentifier
        ORDER BY    RowNumber
    )


SELECT      *
FROM        cte1, cte2
WHERE       cte1.RowNumber BETWEEN (cte2.RowNumber - 10) AND (cte2.RowNumber + 10)
```

`cte1` numbers all rows from 1 to n. `cte2` find the row number for the target row. The final `SELECT` simply scan for the past 10 and next 10 rows.

Comment: This basically works though (judging from the OP's initial code) the row numbering should be applied on rows matching the user so cte1 needs a filter on `UserName = @UserName`. The disadvantage compared to the `MAX() OVER()` in my answer is that this does the row numbering twice so you can end up sorting the whole table twice  http://i.stack.imgur.com/0PNCn.png

Answer (score 1):

Here is pseudo-code for a ROW_NUMBER solution:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
SELECT desiredcolumns, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateCol) AS rn
FROM MyTable
),
cte2 AS (
SELECT ID, rn
FROM cte1
WHERE TextIdentifier = @TextIdentifier 
)
SELECT desiredcolumns
FROM cte1
CROSS JOIN cte2
WHERE cte1.rn > cte2.rn - 10
AND cte1.rn < cte2.rn + 9
```